# IBM Lotus Notes 6.x view txn log files

Tags: ibm, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I have a situation where I need to view the transaction logs on my lotus notes 6.x server.  These logs are stored as 64mb .txn binary files.

Is there a way to directly view it on the server or export it to a .txt format?  I did come across a link to export .txn file to .txt file, but I am unable to find it now.

Forgive me if there was a direct link to this query that I missed, any help is appreciated.